# Nvidia and Ubuntu 17.04, dkms module problem

Tags: nvidia, login

Just updated from 16.10, classic infinite login problem, I always solved re-installing manually the driver.

Downloaded from another pc and sent via `scp`, then:

- `lightdm stop`
- `chmod +x`
- `sudo ./NVIDIA..`

.. building dkms module..

sbam:

[image]

this is the [`make.log`](https://gist.github.com/elect86/b93dc40e60b40fd84302daac058aeb11)

Unistalling the old one and rebooting didn't help

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, more [here](https://github.com/aniljava/nvidia-375.39-patch-linux-4.10)

`wget goo.gl/3c7WU5 -o downloader`

`sudo chmod +x 3c7WU5`

`sudo ./3c7WU5`

it will download the driver 375.39 and patch it, it will fail the execution because the last line is [wrong](https://github.com/aniljava/nvidia-375.39-patch-linux-4.10/issues/1) but who cares, modify the script or launch the patched driver the normal way:
`sudo ./NVIDIA...`

Damned Nvidia.. lost one hour for this

Edit: after a couple of days of issues (waking up from standby, screen corrupted and random crashes), I returned to the `nvidia-375` driver available through repo..